# MMQGIS Python Error Message: "Null geometry cannot be converted to a point"

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

Sorry in advance: I'm a newb...

I have a shapefile layer that I created from a CSV; I want to create a buffer for each point with MMQGIS. I did so successfully with a similar dataset using the same process, but it will not work with this particular one. I checked the data and they look just like the data that worked.

Whenever I try to make the buffer in MMQGIS, it returns the error `"Null geometry cannot be converted to a point."`

I'm running QGIS 3.6, and python 3.6.8 on macOS 10.14.4.

I have looked all over for answers and I cannot figure out what to do. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very simple. Fix it using the approach:

Step 1: Open attribute table and check blank or null values in the coordinates column for both X and Y
Step 2: Delete all blank rows matching the columns identified and save the attribute table or CSV
Step 3. Save edits. Accept changes and run the process, it should work pretty fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use mmqgis for this - use the buffer tool from the Processing toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

One or several features in your SHP may not have proper geometry ?

Quick way to check: create a new text field with value : geom_to_wkt($geometry). The WKT representation might tell you if some geom are funny/missing.